# NsXmlParser do not work properly

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsxmlparser

Hi I have a really strange problem I have xml file whit 21 elements and I want to add them to mutable array.And the parser 11 times start element, 11 times foundCharacters but only 10 times end the element and it behave like it end the xml file.My program do not fall and run like it should run.But some times it makes what it should so it read all the 21 elements.
Why?

some part of my code:

```
 /*this function start work whith xml file*/

- (void)parseXMLFile:(NSData *)adatok {
    if (adatok != nil) {
        BOOL success;
        if (addressParser) 
            [addressParser release];
        addressParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:adatok];
        [addressParser setDelegate:self];
        [addressParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
        success = [addressParser parse]; 

    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    NSLog(elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"turnover"]) {
        objektObrat =[[Obrat1 alloc] init]; 
        NSString *sth = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"transid"];
        objektObrat.uID = sth;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"amount"]) {
        osuma=YES;
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
//filling the object which will be saved in database    
    NSLog(string);
    if (osuma) {
        osuma=NO;
        objektObrat.suma = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    NSLog(elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"turnover"]) {
        turnOver = NO;
        oid = NO;

        if (objektObrat != Nil){
            [obratDatabaseArray addObject:objektObrat];
            [objektObrat release];
        }
        //add to array
        [array addObject:vypisObratString];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"amount"]) {
        osuma=NO;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps, At least one key where I should look for the problem
Thanks

XML

```
<!ELEMENT turnovers (turnover*)>
<!ELEMENT turnover (amount, maturity-date, trans-date, counter-prefix, counter-account, counter-bank, counter-name, constant-symb, variable-symb, spec-symb, description, note, type, storno, rate, balance, currency, statement, message1, message2)> - detail obratu
<!ATTLIST turnover transid CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT amount (#PCDATA)> - suma
<!ELEMENT maturity-date (#PCDATA)> - dátum operácie
<!ELEMENT trans-date (#PCDATA)> - dátum transakcie
<!ELEMENT counter-prefix (#PCDATA)> - predčíslo protiúčtu
<!ELEMENT counter-account (#PCDATA)> - číslo protiúčtu
<!ELEMENT counter-bank (#PCDATA)> - kód banky
<!ELEMENT counter-name (#PCDATA)> - názov protiúčtu
<!ELEMENT constant-symb (#PCDATA)> - konštantný symbol
<!ELEMENT variable-symbol (#PCDATA)> - variabilný symbol
<!ELEMENT spec-symb (#PCDATA)> - špecifický symbol
<!ELEMENT constant-symb (#PCDATA)> - konštantný symbol
<!ELEMENT note (#PCDATA)> - poznamka
<!ELEMENT type (#PCDATA)> - typ obratu pozri číselník typy obratov v prílohe č. 1).
<!ELEMENT storno (#PCDATA)> - či je storno
<!ELEMENT rate (#PCDATA)> - kurz
<!ELEMENT balance (#PCDATA)> - zostatok
<!ELEMENT currency (#PCDATA)> - mena
<!ELEMENT statement (#PCDATA)> - číslo výpisu
<!ELEMENT message1 (#PCDATA)> - message 1
<!ELEMENT message2 (#PCDATA> - message 2
```

Comment: More related code would help. Also, what language is your XML doc in?

Comment: ok I have it in utf-8 and what should I paste here from my code?

Comment: Sorry the xml I can not show you because it contains secret data...but it is valid i m sure.

Comment: I don't say it is not valid, just schematic tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it might be a CDATA. It if you have a tag which has CDATA then CData is parsed through the function

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
```

Check this out.

Comment: I will check it out at transid but i do not understand why it works 10 times

Comment: It works because 10 of your tags are not CDATA blocks, and 1 of them is a CDAta block.

Comment: I found what makes the mistake for me my xml file is 40 KB large and it first gets 8 Kb then it turn his buffer bigger and gets 40 it works corectly when i run my function twice But i do not want to do this so Can i somewhere change the buffer bigger then 8 kb?

Comment: There should not be any problem with buffer of 40 kb. We are parsing much more bigger XML's and didn't even get such problems.